# Maximising $x+y$ such that $x^4=(x-1)(y^3-23)-1$ using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: partial-derivative, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I came across this problem:

> Let x, y be positive integers such that $ x^4 = (x-1)(y^3-23) - 1 $.
> Find maximum possible value of $ x + y $

which I tried to solve using Lagrange Multipliers:

$ f(x,y) = x + y $ 
$ g(x, y) = x^4 - (x-1)(y^3-23) + 1 $

$ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + \lambda\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x} = 0$ 
$ \implies 1 + \lambda[ 4x^3 - (y^3-23)] = 0 \quad\to \ (i)$

$ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} + \lambda\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} = 0$ 
$ \implies 1 + \lambda[ -3y^2(x-1) ] = 0 \quad\to \ (ii)$

$ g(x,y) = 0$ 
$ \implies x^4 - (x-1)(y^3-23) + 1 = 0 \quad\to \ (iii)$

However with this, I couldn't reach to a solution, plotting the curves didn't benefit either. What crucial step am I overlooking?

The given answer is: $x+y=7$

Comment: The fact that only integer solutions are allowed suggests that Lagrange won't be of much use.  Even if you found a solution that way, it may or may not be the case that the optimal integer solution is near it.  I'd look for the integer points on the constraint curve.  Other than $(3,4)$ are there any?

Comment: Yeah that way would work however I specifically was looking for a pragmatic solution to deal it with

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  Integer optimization is hard.  Continuous methods are extremely unreliable.  At best, continuous methods point you to the region where critical points are likely to be...but it can be extremely difficult to know if you are in the right region or not.   Here you are lucky because there really aren't any integer points.  In general, there will be lots and lots of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Remark**: First, this problem cannot be solved with Lagrange Multiplier technique as $(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}_+^2$.

We have:
$$(x-1)(y^3-23)= x^4 +1 =(x^4-2x^2+1)+2x^2=(x^2-1)^2 + 2x^2 = (x-1)^2(x+1)^2 +2x^2$$
We deduce then $(x-1) |2x^2$. As the greatest common divisor of $(x-1)$ and $x$ is $1$, we must have $$x-1 |2$$
$$\implies \cases{x-1= 1\\x-1=2} \iff\cases{x= 2\\x=3}$$
If  $x = 2$ then $2^4 = y^3 - 23 -1 \implies y \not \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $x = 3$ then we have : $3^4 = (3-1)(y^3 -23) -1 \iff y = 4$.

So, with the constraint $x^4 = (x-1)(y^3-23)-1 $, the maximum value (or even the only value) of $x + y$ is $ 7$.